# Maximum Likelihood Estimation for $\theta$ in R

Tags: statistics

I need to find estimate for the unknown $\theta$ with MLE using the R language if i'm given the following sample: $2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8$. The sample is obtained from a discrete distribution with the rules:

$$P(2) = \theta\quad \text{and}\quad P(8) = 1-\theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why R language! You could do it by hand. The estimator is $\hat{\theta}=5/8$. This a Bernoulli random variable. The MLE (of the parameter which is the probability of observing 2's) is the sample mean (proportion of 2's).

In R, it is

> y <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
>
> thetahat <- mean(y)
>
> print(thetahat)

Comment: I know how to do it by hand. The assignment i have is to do it in R.